# Recover audio CD after safecopy

Tags: audio-cd, safecopy

I have an audio CD (burnt a few years ago) that I want to rip (with `K3B` or other) to `flac`. `K3B` was unable to complete and I realized the CD was damaged.

I managed to recover the data with `safecopy` and the `--stage-1-3` arguments. From the output (see below) it seems that the data was properly recovered.

However, I expected to be able to mount the file and take it from there. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the case:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 diskimage /media/cdrom1/
mount: block device /mnt/data/Bureau/diskimage is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

`dmesg` doesn't show much useful output:

```
$ dmesg | tail
ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

Indeed it seems to be in an unrecognized format:

```
$ file diskimage 
diskimage: data
```

Unsurprisingly, renaming the file to `.iso`, `.raw`, `.img` or `.bin` made no difference.

Some people on the Internet recommend using `ccd2iso` but it fails as well (`Unrecognized sector mode (0) at sector 0!`).

How can I proceed to extract the audio from this raw data dump?

Here is the output from `safecopy`. The `stage3.badblocks` is empty.

```
$ safecopy /dev/sr0 diskimage --stage1
Low level device calls enabled mode: 2
Reported hw blocksize: 4096
CDROM audio - low level access: drive reset, raw read
CDROM low level disk size: 784954128
CDROM low level block size: 2352
Reported low level blocksize: 2352
File size: 784954128
Blocksize: 2352
Fault skip blocksize: 78493296
Resolution: 78493296
Min read attempts: 1
Head moves on read error: 0
Badblocks output: stage1.badblocks
Marker string: BaDbLoCk
Starting block: 0
Source: /dev/sr0
Destination: diskimage
......................................... [40961]    
......................................... [82945]    
......................................... [124929]    
......................................... [166913]    
......................................... [208897]    
......................................... [250881]    
................................[284577](+669325104){X [317950]    
}[317950](+78493296)
................[333739](+37135728){X}[367112](+78493296)

Done!
Recovered bad blocks: 0
Unrecoverable bad blocks (bytes): 2 (156986592)
Blocks (bytes) copied: 333739 (784954128)

xavier@marvin:~/Bureau$ safecopy /dev/sr0 diskimage --stage2
Low level device calls enabled mode: 2
Reported hw blocksize: 4096
CDROM audio - low level access: drive reset, raw read
CDROM low level disk size: 784954128
CDROM low level block size: 2352
Reported low level blocksize: 2352
File size: 784954128
Blocksize: 2352
Fault skip blocksize: 301056
Resolution: 2352
Min read attempts: 1
Head moves on read error: 0
Incremental mode file: stage1.badblocks
Incremental mode blocksize: 2352
Badblocks output: stage2.badblocks
Starting block: 0
Source: /dev/sr0
Destination: diskimage
Current destination size: 863447424
........................[309047](+726878544){X [309175]    
<<<<<<<}[309048](+2352)
.....[313338](+10090080){X<<<<<<<}[313339](+2352)
.....  8-( 95%
Done!
Recovered bad blocks: 0
Unrecoverable bad blocks (bytes): 2 (4704)
Blocks (bytes) copied: 317950 (747818400)

$ safecopy /dev/sr0 diskimage --stage3
Low level device calls enabled mode: 2
Reported hw blocksize: 4096
CDROM audio - low level access: drive reset, raw read
CDROM low level disk size: 784954128
CDROM low level block size: 2352
Reported low level blocksize: 2352
File size: 784954128
Blocksize: 2352
Fault skip blocksize: 2352
Resolution: 2352
Min read attempts: 4
Head moves on read error: 1
Incremental mode file: stage2.badblocks
Incremental mode blocksize: 2352
Badblocks output: stage3.badblocks
Starting block: 0
Source: /dev/sr0
Destination: diskimage
Current destination size: 863447424
.  8-( 93%
Done!
Recovered bad blocks: 0
Unrecoverable bad blocks (bytes): 0 (0)
Blocks (bytes) copied: 313339 (736973328)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a file system on standard audio CD so you can't mount that image file. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio . I guess you can associate it to a `/dev/loop` entry using `losetup`, but I've never tried doing that with CDDA data myself. But why not just burn the image to a new disk?

Comment: @PM2Ring because it doesn't work. For instance K3B tells me "Seems not to be a usable image"... I'll try to `losetup` thing.

Comment: I don't like your chances if KB3 says the image is faulty, but it might be worthwhile seeing if `cdparanoia` can do something with it.

Comment: To find the first unused loop device do (as root) `losetup -f`. If it returns `/dev/loop1` then do `losetup /dev/loop1 diskimage`, assuming `diskimage` is the name of your image file. Then to tell `cdparanoia` to use that device instead of `/dev/cdrom` you do `cdparanoia -d /dev/loop1`. Of course you will also need to supply other parameters to `cdparanoia`. And I have no idea if this will actually work. :)

Comment: Thanks for that info, @schily.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem I wished to recover a CD that started jumping in my CD player. I searched on line to find an answer but to no avail. But experimenting I found you can import the recovered file into Audacity as raw data. Then you can separate the tracks and re-encode as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I used safecopy to get the image and used audacity to get the tracks